# vector space of natural numbers

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

I wonder, is it possible for the natural numbers (with zero) t be a vector  space on SOME field? I understand why it cannot be over real numbers because of muliplication with negative scalar. BUT what about modulo3 field that have only positive numbers or  OTHER field. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

For one thing, you need additive inverses for vectors.